# Stack and heap issue for iPhone memory management 

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

*Why are all objects in Objective-C allocated in the heap instead of on the stack?

How about if we program with both Objective-C and C++?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear what you are asking.

If you are asking about things like `NSString* str = @"hello";`, then that was answered in the question you linked to.

*Why there is no heap?* doesn't make sense.  There very much is a heap in iOS applications and objects are allocated from it.

The mention of "automatic objects" and/or `auto_ptr` from the "post" you mention is entirely unrelated to Objective-C.

Clarify your question, please.

Answer (score 1):

1. *All Object C objects should be alloc in stack ? ( I think yes )*

   **No.**  As the quote in your question says, "the Objective-C runtime does not allow objects to be instantiated on the stack"
2. *In C++, there are stack for memory, so for iOS app, also have stack ? ( I think yes )*

   Yes, there is a stack in Objective-C. Objects simply aren't allocated there.